# Using Middleware in react-hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

So I am using redux for state management in my react-native app.
I was looking forward to use hooks in my app.
My store has multiple instances of a single reducer so dispatching actions to a single reducer is kind of a pain to deal with.

Hooks seem to provide a really neat solution in such a situation.
We are using middle-ware to catch specific actions and perform side-effect. 
I was hoping to implement a middle-ware like functionality for hooks wherein action dispatched to the hooks can also be caught in the redux-middleware.

Any suggestions as to how such functionality can be achieved would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have ever hear or you try redux-saga for your middleware asynchronous things like data fetching and impure things like accessing the browser cache its easier to manage, more efficient to execute, easy to test, and better at handling failures.

for more complete documentation you can see in [here](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga)

i give you simple example for using redux saga as side effect

```
import api from '../api/apidetailproduct'; //if using api import it
import {
    takeLatest, //Spawns a saga on each action dispatched to the Store that matches pattern
    select, //instructs the middleware to invoke the provided selector on the current Store's state
    call, //for calling api
    put //instructs the middleware to dispatch an action to the Store. 
} from 'redux-saga/effects';
import {
    REQUEST_PRODUCT, 
} from '../actions/constants';
import {
    responseProduct,
} from '../actions/product';

export function* detailEffect(){
    const {loginreducer} = yield select() //first select your reducer where you store
    try {
        const {data} = yield call(api, loginreducer.token )//calling the api and then send the variable
        yield put(responseProduct(data))//put the data
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("error", error);
    }
}

export const productsagas = [takeLatest(REQUEST_PRODUCT, detailEffect)]
```

Comment: I don't believe this answer addresses the question. The questioner wanted to know how to use React hooks in conjunction with middleware in a manner similar to Redux. The answer above offers a middleware for Redux, but it provides no information about how to apply it or any other middleware to React hooks.